# Keeping li elements contained in navbar

Tags: html, css, styling

For the most part, my navbar behaves as I want it to, but as I git closer to a screen size of 600px, my li elements start to go outside the boundaries of the navbar and its my intention to always keep them inside there.

Keeping things in their fixed position is something I'm struggling with a bit in a few other areas as well. Here is the HTML:

```
 <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="header-black">
          <img src="resources/img/logo-header.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
          <i class="ion-navicon-round icon-small"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="header-pages">
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><i class="ion-ios-person icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#single-attendee">
                <p>Single Atendee</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><i class="ion-ios-people icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#group-tickets">
                <p>Group Tickets</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><i class="ion-arrow-move icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#investors">
                <p>Investors</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><i class="ion-location icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#startups">
                <p>StartUps</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.header-pages {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #F6FBFC;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-pages nav ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-pages nav ul li {
  min-width: 55px;
}

.header-pages .main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #cccccc;
  text: #cccccc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30%;
}


.header-pages .main-nav li p {
  padding-top: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  float:right;
}



.header-pages .main-nav li:hover a,
.header-pages .main-nav li:hover i,
.header-pages .main-nav li:hover p
 {
  color: #0198E1;
}


.header-pages .main-nav li a:focus i,
.header-pages .main-nav li a:focus p
 {
  color: #0198E1;
}
```

Comment: If @Johannes' answer doesn't work, you might need to give us more info. I copied and pasted your files, opened them in Chrome, and even at 110px wide the `li`s stay within the `nav`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The li elements will need to wrap into two lines at some point (unless you find another solution, like a nav-icon and a hidden vertical menu that only appears on click or mouseover).

The only thing you have to change for your navbar background to cover your  li elements is to change its "height" property to "min-height" , which will allow it to become higher according to its contents:

```css
.header-pages {
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: #F6FBFC;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-pages nav ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-pages nav ul li {
  min-width: 55px;
}

.header-pages .main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #cccccc;
  text: #cccccc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30%;
}


.header-pages .main-nav li p {
  padding-top: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  float:right;
}



.header-pages .main-nav li:hover a,
.header-pages .main-nav li:hover i,
.header-pages .main-nav li:hover p
 {
  color: #0198E1;
}


.header-pages .main-nav li a:focus i,
.header-pages .main-nav li a:focus p
 {
  color: #0198E1;
}
```

```html
 <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="header-black">
          <img src="resources/img/logo-header.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
          <i class="ion-navicon-round icon-small"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="header-pages">
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><i class="ion-ios-person icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#single-attendee">
                <p>Single Atendee</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><i class="ion-ios-people icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#group-tickets">
                <p>Group Tickets</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><i class="ion-arrow-move icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#investors">
                <p>Investors</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><i class="ion-location icon-small"></i>
              <a href="#startups">
                <p>StartUps</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the best solution for what I am looking for.